# Batch program not running correctly in Windows 7

Tags: file, windows-7, batch-file

I am currently trying to figure out how to get a batch file to run correctly in Windows 7.  I have looked on the Internet and have not had much success in finding any useful information on the issue I am encountering.

BATCH FILE – The batch file is to open a window to allow students to test on a TDSM server created by ETS eCBT – The test is a CLEP Exam.  The batch file is to open the workstation for students to use and it looks like it loads but the Welcome/Login Screen never appears as it should.

WSK_LOAD.BAT

```
@echo off
rem--------------------------------------------------------------------
rem  !!! DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS FILE   !!!
rem  !!! THIS FILE IS USED BY THE eCBT SYSTEM !!!
rem--------------------------------------------------------------------
SET ECBT_DEFAULT_SERVER_NAME=WR-TESTING1
SET ECBT_BATCH_HOME=C:\ETSBATCH
SET ECBT_HOME=\\WR-TESTING1\tdms
set ECBT_LOGFILE=%ECBT_BATCH_HOME%\wsk.log
SET ECBT_CLIENT_VERSION=4.0
rem----------------------------------------------------------------------
if exist %ECBT_HOME%\client\bin\wks.bat goto avail
echo Cannot access %ECBT_HOME%!
echo Attempting to open the share …
echo If you see the share window, please close it to proceed …
rem------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
:avail
%ECBT_HOME%\client\bin\wks.bat
```

I have tried everything I can think of:  Run as Administrator, Moved files to run from the HD, made sure all files and folders associated with the program were shared with users and computers, had Windows 7 run compatibility which says it does not contain an .exe file to run, and re-wrote the file.

I know it is connecting to the TDMS server as I can see it on the server.  The only thing it does not do is bring up the window which is necessary to login to the testing server.  The window opens like it should but does not produce the login boxes.
Any and all help is appreciated,
Jennifer

Comment: All a batch file does is run each command as if you had typed it in yourself at the command line. Does the same thing occur if you type each line in manually (minus the rems, echos and if, of course)?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in this script and not in `wks.bat`?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this helps you at this point, but after contacting ETS, I found that the client side workstation script is not compatible with Windows 7 64-bit. Although it does work with Windows 7 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Well my first recommendation is to try debugging your "WKS_LOAD.BAT" script to check for errors or mistakes that you may have over-looked.

Comment: Heres a website that explains a basic method of how to debug a batch script. 

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php

Also, take a look at this very detailed answer to a similar question on this site:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165938/how-can-i-debug-a-bat-script

Comment: And if none of what i suggested works, then go with "jamesdlin"'s response, because he does make a good point, it could be a server-side problem.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your server is started.

If you are on the server it may not ever find the server (itself) automatically. You should find it automatically on a client install, but will have to specify it on the server manually. Luckily the default settings work when connecting from the host server.

I contacted their support line and received worthless, uninformed advice that led nowhere.

If you do not get the prompt to specify a server, something else is wrong. This system relies heavily on Java. That batch script calls another batch script which checks for updates, then loads a jar executable into the JVM.