# Running a batch script one statement at a time?

Tags: debugging, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to debug a complex CMD batch script. Is there a way to run it one statement at a time, like how some IDEs allow you to run your program step-by-step?

In addition, I would like to log everything (each statement and its result after evaluation) to a log file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165938/how-can-i-debug-a-bat-script

Comment: Also see http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php

Answer (score 1):

This works for all commands (I managed to test in short notice) except for `goto` and `for`, as well as commands extending multiple lines.

It is a draft and can be improved.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims== tokens=*" %%a in (target.bat) do (
echo.
echo %%a
echo %%a >> log.txt
pause
%%a
)
```

It tells you what command its about to run and puts it into the log.txt file.
Then upon pressing a key it runs the command.

If some one can  improve this please tell me how.

Hope this helped. Mona.