# Windows - Kafka Start Server not starting

Tags: apache-kafka

I everyone, first time using Kafka (& Zookeeper) and so i followed some tutorials that lead to me to a problem. I'm able to run Zookeper but when I try to run Kafka using `.\kafka-server-start.bat C:\kafka\config\server.properties` i get the following output on the image.

[Kafka output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G60U.png)

Any idea on what it could be? I have JDK installed and  working:

```
PS C:\kafka\bin\windows> java -version
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

Zookeeper with variables set and done but Kafka keeps on not starting.

[Zookeeper output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7kuW.png)

My Zookeeper conf file is as follows:

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial 
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between 
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just 
# example sakes.
dataDir=./logs
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
maxClientCnxns=60
```

Didn't change a thing on the Server.properties file.

Comment: Did you modify kafka-server-start.bat?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/165938/2308683

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the environment variables corretly?

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_201 (or your jdk version)
```

```
PATH += %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: Yes, I have both my JAVA_HOME and PATH set with the path for my JDK folder

Comment: Try running `.\kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties`, also can you share what you have on `zookeeper.properties` and `server.properties`?

Comment: I updated my question with the contents of the Zookeeper terminal output and the Conf file.

Comment: Can we see the content of kafka-server-start.bat ?

Comment: @Yannick it's on Github