# SET command with spaces causes "was unexpected at this time" eror

Tags: batch-file

When I use SET with spaces in the text I receive an error message. Why? Note: this call is inside of another function, I am using setlocal enabledelayedexpansion set at beginning of file.

**This works with no error (no spaces in SET text):**

```
:: Is the host up?
CALL :TEST_HOST_UP %REMOTE_SYSTEM%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    set "RETVAL=Error_Unable_To_Reach_Host"
    GOTO :FINISHED
)
```

**Causes an error "was unexpected at this time":**

```
:: Is the host up?
CALL :TEST_HOST_UP %REMOTE_SYSTEM%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    set "RETVAL=Error Unable To Reach Host"
    GOTO :FINISHED
)
```

Comment: The error does not come from (just) the fragment you posted. Try to turn `echo on` and save some more context around the point of failure.

Comment: @dxiv your pointers led me to the problem immediately. I turned 'echo on' and found that it was correctly assigning SET and jumping to :FINISHED. That section though had code without quotes around the string used in an IF. I fixed it like so if "[%RETVAL%]"=="[No_Errors_Found]" (.   If you respond to the question formally, I will up vote and select it as the correct answer.

Comment: Glad it helped, but it was just what it was - a comment. If you want to post a self-answer with the details and the resolution I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: Thanks again. I provided a self answer. @dxiv

Answer (score 1):

The error message **"was unexepected at this time"** was actually a problem in the IF statement somewhere else in the code:

```
if [%RETVAL%]==[No_Errors_Found] (
```

Which is a common concern in scripting languages such as batch or shell, where you must put quotes around your variables:

```
if "[%RETVAL%]"=="[No_Errors_Found]" (
```

Thanks to @dxiv's help, I was able to debug the problem immediately - mainly by adding '**echo on**' command to the code to provide verbose output.

More information on debugging batch scripts can be found here:
[How can I debug a .BAT script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165938/how-can-i-debug-a-bat-script)