# Game Crashes After Playing The First Round, How Can I Get It To Function Correctly?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So, I am working on a batch TD game, and whenever i test it and play through Round 1, It crashes instantly. I have no idea what could cause this. I'll send the code, Thanks in advance! (healing and conceding doesnt work right now)

```
@echo off
goto gamediff
:gamediff
cls
echo GAME COLOUR
echo.
echo [1] Blue (Easy)
echo [2] Yellow (Normal)
echo [3] Red (Hard)
set /p col=
if %col% == 1 set /a cashamm= 500 & set /a damamm= 30 & goto gameload
if %col% == 2 set /a cashamm= 250 & set /a damamm= 50 & goto gameload
if %col% == 3 set /a cashamm= 250 & set /a damamm= 60 & goto gameload
goto gamediff
:gameload
set /a turn= 1
set /a basic= 0
set /a heavy= 0
set /a snip= 0
set /a total= 0
set /a cash= %cashamm%
set /a dam= %damamm%
set /a attack= 0
set /a heal= 3
set /a health= 500
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
if %col% == 1 color b0
if %col% == 2 color f0
if %col% == 3 color c0
goto game
:game
cls
set /a nonpro= %dam%
echo Round %turn%
echo Cash: %cash%
echo Opponent Damage: %dam%
echo Your Protection: %attack%
echo Helth: %health%
echo.
echo STATS
echo Basic Troops: %basic%
echo Heavy Troops: %heavy%
echo Sniping Troops: %snip%
echo TOTAL: %total%
echo.
echo.
echo [0] Concede
echo [1] Play Round
echo [2] Recruitment
echo [3] Heal (Heals left: %heal%)
set /p gamin=
if %gamin% == 0 goto lose
if %gamin% == 1 goto play
if %gamin% == 2 goto shop
if %gamin% == 3 goto healtime
goto game
:play
cls
echo YOU PROTECT!
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
echo %attack% PROTECTED 
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 > nul
echo.
echo THEY ATTACK!
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
set /a nonpro-= %attack%
if %nonpro% LSS 1 set /a nonpro= 0
set /a health-= %nonpro%
echo -%nonpro% HEALTH!
pause
if %health% LSS 1 goto lose
if %round% GTR 50 goto win
set /a round+= 1
set /a dam+= %random% %% 20
set /a cash+= %random% %% 100
goto game
:shop
cls
echo Recruitment
echo.
echo [0] Leave
echo [1] Basic Troop (-50 Cash, +15 Protection)
echo [2] Heavy Troop (-100 Cash, +40 Protection)
echo [3] Sniping Troop (-70 Cash,+25 Protection)
set /p shope=
if %shope% == 0 goto game
if %shope% == 1 goto buy1
if %shope% == 2 goto buy2
if %shope% == 3 goto buy3
goto shop
:buy1
if cash LSS 50 goto game
set /a cash-= 50
set /a attack+= 15
goto game
:buy2
if cash LSS 100 goto game
set /a cash-= 100
set /a attack+= 40
goto game
:buy3
if cash LSS 70 goto game
set /a cash-= 70
set /a attack+= 25
goto game
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me!
If you need more information, please ask for it in the comments.

Comment: You should start by debugging your batch (tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165938/how-can-i-debug-a-bat-script) to point out where the issue is. Then if you are not able to fix it, you can add more info so one can help you.

Comment: `if VAR equ 100` will never equal, you should use `if %VAR% equ 100`…

Answer (score -1):

You can contact me through whatever this site has if you run into any more problems. I can also help you with any questions you have, quickly.

`lose` and `win` are non-existent labels. Use quotations when using `if`, and also with `set` unless you're declaring a variable as another. The `/a` switch is not necessary for `set` whenever arithmetic is not being performed.

Other proper things to do while writing in batch:

--In a `goto` statement ensure the label is preceded with a colon `:`.

--When prompting user input in the form of selection with under 9 options, use the `choice` command. It's more suitable.

--Your variable names should make sense.

--Batch is slow, inefficient, unreliable, elementary, featureless, and basic. Opt for a better coding language that's simple but much, much better, like VB.NET or Python. Batch is barely even a coding language.

The following code has most of the problems I mentioned fixed, except for the `choice` one because, in some cases, `set` could be a better option.

```
@echo off
goto gamediff
:gamediff
cls
echo GAME COLOUR
echo.
echo [1] Blue (Easy)
echo [2] Yellow (Normal)
echo [3] Red (Hard)
set /p "col=>"
if %col% == 1 set /a cashamm = 500 & set /a damamm = 30 & goto gameload
if %col% == 2 set /a cashamm = 250 & set /a damamm = 50 & goto gameload
if %col% == 3 set /a cashamm = 250 & set /a damamm = 60 & goto gameload
goto :gamediff

:gameload
set /a turn = 1
set /a basic = 0
set /a heavy = 0
set /a snip = 0
set /a total = 0
set /a cash = %cashamm%
set /a dam = %damamm%
set /a attack = 0
set /a heal = 3
set /a health = 500
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
if %col% == 1 color b0
if %col% == 2 color f0
if %col% == 3 color c0
goto :game

:game
cls
set /a nonpro = %dam%
echo Round %turn%
echo Cash: %cash%
echo Opponent Damage: %dam%
echo Your Protection: %attack%
echo Health: %health%
echo.
echo STATS
echo Basic Troops: %basic%
echo Heavy Troops: %heavy%
echo Sniping Troops: %snip%
echo TOTAL: %total%
echo.
echo.
echo [0] Concede
echo [1] Play Round
echo [2] Recruitment
echo [3] Heal (Heals left: %heal%)
set/p "gamin=>"
if %gamin% == 0 goto lose
if %gamin% == 1 goto play
if %gamin% == 2 goto shop
if %gamin% == 3 goto healtime
goto :game
:play
cls
echo YOU PROTECT!
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >NUL
echo %attack% PROTECTED 
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >NUL
echo.
echo THEY ATTACK!
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >NUL
set /a nonpro -= %attack%
if "%nonpro%" LSS "1" set /a nonpro = 0
set /a health -= %nonpro%
echo -%nonpro% HEALTH!
if "%health%" LSS "1" goto :lose
if "%round%" GTR "50" goto :win
set /a round += 1
set /a dam += %random% %% 20
set /a cash += %random% %% 100
goto :game

:shop
cls
echo Recruitment
echo.
echo [0] Leave
echo [1] Basic Troop (-50 Cash, +15 Protection)
echo [2] Heavy Troop (-100 Cash, +40 Protection)
echo [3] Sniping Troop (-70 Cash,+25 Protection)
set /p "shope=>"
if "%shope%" == "0" goto :game
if "%shope%" == "1" goto :buy1
if "%shope%" == "2" goto :buy2
if "%shope%" == "3" goto :buy3
goto :shop

:buy1
if "%cash%" LSS "50" goto :game
set /a cash -= 50
set /a attack += 15
goto :game

:buy2
if "%cash%" LSS "100" goto :game
set /a cash -= 100
set /a attack += 40
goto :game

:buy3
if "%cash%" LSS "70" goto :game
set /a cash -= 70
set /a attack += 25
goto :game

:lose
REM When the player loses, run this code
goto :game

:win
REM When the player wins, run this code
goto :game
```

Also, your shop doesn't work. Also also I tested your code I modified and it does work

Comment: i had realised one of the functions was spelt incorrectly, thanks for rreaching out though!

Comment: @KuaNai There's no functions in your code, so you're wrong. My advice still applies regardless.